# Dangjo with Mongodb, spaces in field name: FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword '' into field

Tags: python, django, mongodb

Short-time lurker looking for a bit of guidance. I started a small project to automate a little of the day-to-day. I chose Python and from here I have become interested in programming. About a month ago I decided to keep track of what was going on and hooked up a MongoDB instance to the automated process. Moving onto a GUI using Django. I have hit an issue with one of my views and I suspect the answer will likely be to remove spaces from field names but thought I would ask here as a hail mary :)

When trying to apply a filter to my objects it returns the following error:

```
Error:
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword '' into field. Choices are: NP Title ID, Product Code, Product Type, _id
```

Problem model and view below:

```
Model:
    class Railway_Products(models.Model):
        _id = models.ObjectIdField(name='_id', editable=False)
        np_title_id = models.CharField(name='NP Title ID', max_length=15)
        product_type = models.CharField(name='Product Type', max_length=15)
        product_code = models.CharField(name='Product Code', max_length=15)

class Meta:
    db_table = "Products"
    verbose_name_plural = "products"

View:
    class Railway_Products_ListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Railway_Products
    context_object_name = 'product_list'
    queryset = model.objects.filter(name='NP Title ID',__icontains='PPSA')
```

I know the issue is this line:

```
queryset = model.objects.filter(name='NP Title ID',__icontains='PPSA')
```

and name= not enjoying the '' or simply not being accepted. I have tried assigning 'NP Title ID' to a variable. Which just results in Cannot resolve **variablename** into the field. As a quick test, I renamed the field within the MongoDB, model and view to NPTitleID. As below:

```
queryset = model.objects.filter(NPTitleID__icontains='PPSA')
```

which works. However, I would like to avoid renaming field names within collections as these have all been set up with spaces. Is there a way I can get this to work with the spaces intact?

UPDATE with @AKX answer below:

```
model:
np_title_id = models.CharField(name='NPTitleID', db_column='NP Title ID', max_length=15)

view:
queryset = model.objects.all().filter(NPTitleID__icontains='PPSA')
```

This returns the expected results to the view with no errors. Had to do a little rename on the admin side filters changing 'NP Title ID' to 'NPTitleID' but this was much more preferable to changing all field names within MongoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django doesn't support MongoDB for its ORM by default, so this is a bit of a shot in the dark.

If your Django/MongoDB adapter works like Django works by default, you can [set `db_column` on each field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#db-column) to what the actual field is in the database, e.g.

```
np_title_id = models.CharField(
    max_length=15,
    db_column='NP Title ID',
)
```

Comment: Thanks AKX, so the model accepts this without any issues but setting that in the view returns the same error. I have been reading of the Mongodb integration issues but I think the app is a little too far down the line to change everything! It is connected successfully though, I can view records and perform CRUD operations via admin etc

Comment: With this change, `queryset = model.objects.filter(NPTitleID__icontains='PPSA')` should work without having changed anything in MongoDB.